# Convert Warped VR Video to Stereo

Tags: software-recommendation, vr

I'm aware there's a few different VR cameras out there that do different projection types (fisheye, parallax, etc).

I have a video that I want to convert from its warped VR projection to regular left/right stereo. Is this possible? I did a quick google search and there seems to be software for this but I'm not sure it does what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the original “VR video” is not stereoscopic (i.e., monoscopic panorama) and/or does not contain any depth data, then to create stereoscopic video, the second camera angle must be synthesized from the first.  The success of this project depends on the current state of the art machine learning models for view synthesis, and isn’t a simple matter of converting one format to another.

But if the original content does contain left/right pairs, then, yes, changing the projection is relatively simple.  Andrew Hazledon has built a suite of tools for Blackmagic Fusion, called KartaVR, available through Reactor.